# How to get rid of "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set" Exception?

Tags: java, linux, bash

I've created an application in java that can be run on Windows in GUI or in command line, and also on Linux in bash. My problem is that when I run it in Linux I get the  "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set" which I know comes from the fact that I create some frames in my program, but only if it's run on Windows with GUI.

How can I make this exception not appear while running the program in Linux?

Comment: I suggest you `export  DISPLAY={whaterever your display is}` if it is not set it would appear you don't have X-windows configured correctly.  Which X-Server are you using? On windows, I use the free one which comes with Cygwin.

Comment: try `export DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: You should check if the server had a GUI connected to it: `boolean canCreateFrames = !GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().isHeadless()`

Comment: I am connecting remote, so I don't have a display.

Comment: I've tried the solutions proposed in the other post. My question in fact is: how can I hide this message when I run the program. It works perfectly, I just want the exception message not to be displayed anymore.

Comment: Clearly what you think of as your Windows-only code is being executed on Linux. Investigate.